# unable to fetch a value from promise - IONIC2

Tags: angular, ionic2

My php file is returning this as response

"Result:1"

and i am trying to match it in my `.ts` file as follows, which is not working

```
this._login.login(this.usr,this.pwd)
        .subscribe(data => {
          console.log(data[0].Result);
             if(data[0].Result == 1){
                this.navCtrl.push(DashboardPage);
             }
        }
```

in my `console.log` it says undefined. 
Please help me in correcting this 2 lines of code please
`console.log(data[0].Result);
                 if(data[0].Result == 1)`

> Thanks in advance

Comment: How does data array look like?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2mzd3nla21bymto/Screenshot%202017-11-03%2013.53.48.png?dl=0  this is how response looks and this is the code in php -  `echo json_encode("Result:".$cnt);`

Comment: Show your `login` (from `this._login.login`) function, please.

Comment: you need to return data in the right format from the backend...

Comment: Your json_encode() is not creating a json object since you just pass a String e.g. "Result: 1" - try to encode a php Object/array instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks that your php code returns a string, not a json (technically it's string converted to json), but in ionic you treat it like it was a json object. Te response should be: `[{"Result": 1}]` not `Result:1`

so in your php code you need:

`echo json_encode(array(array("Result" => $cnt)));`

Comment: it says unexpected end of json input - https://www.dropbox.com/s/4ae4hrm82mtvffe/Screenshot%202017-11-03%2014.24.03.png?dl=0

Comment: what's the response form php now?

Comment: i need to correct php side , tried this but not working - `json_encode(("Result" => $cnt));` , how can i get result like this `[{"Result":"1"}]

Comment: You forgot the `array` in the line. If you want to have `{"Result": 1}` you need code `json_encode(array("Result" => $cnt));`. But if you want `[{"Result":"1"}]` you need 'two arrays:  `json_encode(array(array("Result" => $cnt)));`

Comment: no result coming in postman using above suggestion- https://www.dropbox.com/s/83ht1td1pbrkyyg/Screenshot%202017-11-03%2015.54.07.png?dl=0  and i need 2 backets `[{ }]`

Comment: Didn't you forget `echo`? `echo json_encode(array(array("Result" => $cnt)));`

Comment: `echo json_encode array(("Result" => $cnt));`  giving this error in postman `<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_ARRAY, expecting ',' or ';' in
<b>/home2/saurabh/public_html/edits/pro/users/funiks/qbook/api/userinfojson.php</b> on line
<b>50</b>
<br />`

Comment: Please copy my line exactly with all the braces: `echo json_encode(array(array("Result" => $cnt)));`

Comment: i can see this result in postman `[
    {
        "Result": "1"
    }
]`  but `console.log(data.Result);` is coming undefined

Comment: If you wanted to have two braces [{ then you need to use `data[0].Result` like at the beginning

Comment: you rock !! please update your answer so i can accept

Answer (score 0):

I think you need like this,

```
this._login.login(this.usr,this.pwd)
        .subscribe(data => {
          console.log(data.Result);
             if(data.Result == 1){
                this.navCtrl.push(DashboardPage);
             }
        }
```

Comment: it still says undefined

Comment: @JessicaStorm try console.log(data); and then paste your result here

Comment: i need to correct php side , tried this but not working - json_encode(("Result" => $cnt)); , how can i get result like this `[{"Result":"1"}]

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot, return type is not JSON it's string. covert the string to JSON. Try the below code

```
 this._login.login(this.usr,this.pwd)
            .subscribe(data => {
let updatedData = JSON.parse("{"+data+"}")
              console.log(updatedData.Result);
                 if(updatedData.Result == 1){
                    this.navCtrl.push(DashboardPage);
                 }
            }
```

Comment: [ts] Property 'Result' does not exist on type 'string'.
any

Comment: sorry updated the code to convert string to JSON. JSON.parse - check this now